# MySQL query to check whether query returns any duplicates

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to check MySQL query to ensure it only returns a single result for each txn_feed.id.  However the below statement is returning a single result with id = 1 and txns = 36963. I'm expecting to see all the txn_id's with a txns = 1 for most/all but txns > 1 for any duplicates. I know it will be something simple, but I'm new to SQL and can't see it.

```
select tf.id, count(*) as txns
from txn_feed as tf left join 
     kiosk as k
     on tf.kiosk_number = k.number left join
     kiosk_deployment as kd on k.id = kd.machine_id
where tf.date_authorised > kd.installed_date and
      ((kd.status = 'Installed') or (kd.status = 'Removed' and tf.date_authorised < kd.uninstalled_date))
order by txns desc;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the aggregated function `count()`, but missed the `group by`. By applying `group by` it will first make the group of distinct id's and return the count.

```
select tf.id, count(*) as txns
from txn_feed as tf left join 
     kiosk as k
     on tf.kiosk_number = k.number left join
     kiosk_deployment as kd on k.id = kd.machine_id
where tf.date_authorised > kd.installed_date and
      ((kd.status = 'Installed') or (kd.status = 'Removed' and tf.date_authorised < kd.uninstalled_date))
      group by tf.id
order by txns desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `group by`:

```
select tf.id, count(*) as txns
from txn_feed tf left join 
     kiosk as k
     on tf.kiosk_number = k.number left join
     kiosk_deployment kd
     on k.id = kd.machine_id
where tf.date_authorised > kd.installed_date and
      ((kd.status = 'Installed') or
       (kd.status = 'Removed' and tf.date_authorised < kd.uninstalled_date)
      )
group by tf.id
order by txns desc;
```